# How can I randomly select data iterating through columns and form a row in Mysql DB?

Tags: java, mysql

Consider the table like below:

***ID    |    Books          |    Book_Stores***

123   |   Harry-P         |    G.F Stores

124   |   Titin        |    Fedup Stores

125   |   CS           |    null

126   |   BioTech      |    null

My expected random output:

If I need four random rows of data:

124 | Harry- P |   Fedup Stores

125 | BioTech  |  G.F Stores

126 | CS       |  G.F Stores

123 | BioTech  |  Fedup Stores

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Get all records and append to `List` and then shuffle using `Collections.shuffle(your_list);`

Comment: Here's one idea - you could echo the first row from each id change in the returned array... http://rextester.com/TEMGWR38826

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also recommend you to specify the language that you want to be used. MySQL or PhP, or another one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of doing that "inside" mysql (it seems rather odd to expect that a database gives you results in random order anyway).

Thus: the simple answer is: shuffle yourself.

- Fetch data from your database; and pull it into different lists *by column*
- Use Collections.shuffle() to put each list in a different random

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GhostCat , MySQL does not shuffle data, you should perhaps select the rows first, then shuffle them using your backend code, and then display.

You could also just retrieve the ids shuffle those and then select using the ids in the order of shuffling.